# undefined variable when rendering underscore template data in backbone

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am using backbone with underscore templates, but I'm having problem getting underscore to render the data I pass along to the template. Here's my code:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/home/HomeModel',
  'text!/app/templates/home/homeTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone,HomeModel,homeTemplate){

  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),

    initialize: function(){
      var self = this;
      self.model = new HomeModel();
    },

    render: function(){
      var homeTitle = this.model.get('title');
      var homeData = {
        title: homeTitle
      }

      var compiledTemplate = _.template( homeTemplate, homeData );
      this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

    }

  });

  return HomeView;

});
```

In this code, I can get all the way to the var homeData = {} object, which includes the proper title from the model, but when I create the compiledTemplate, I get an error saying title is not defined.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you verified your homeData has what you expect? what does your template look like?

Comment: Almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/26367258/479863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Underscore.js documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

> var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
>
> compiled({name: 'moe'});
>
> => "hello: moe"

It looks like you are not using the `_.template` method correctly. It returns a compiled template function that you can call with the data to render:

```
var compiledTemplate = _.template( homeTemplate, homeData );
this.$el.html( compiledTemplate( homeData ) );
```

Comment: You can optionally pass both the template and the data at the same time and have it render with the same call.

Comment: Then the "title" on the model must be undefined.

Comment: @kinakuta: Not as of Underscore 1.7, the two step process is now mandatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863

Comment: I think you want to say `var compiledTemplate = _.template( homeTemplate );` (i.e. no second parameter) just to be sure that nothing in `homeData` conflicts with any `_.template` options.

Comment: @muistooshort ugh, so I see. Now I have to go refactor old code so things don't break if underscore gets updated.