# Object not passing down to template in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to make a JSON call and list the items in it with backbone. I get the items back successfully and am able to confirm they are available with a console log, but when I try passing them into my template I'm getting an error saying

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: quotes is not defined"
```

My code:

```js
var Quotes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/quotes.json'
});

var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.quote-list',
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    var quotes = new Quotes();
    quotes.fetch({
      success: function(quotes) {
        var variables = {
          search: "search"
        };
        var template = _.template($('#quotes-template').html(), variables);
        console.log(template)
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "home"
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var userListView = new UserListView;
  var router = new Router;
  router.on('route:home', function() {
    //render user list
    userListView.render();
  });

  Backbone.history.start();

})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="quote-list"></div>

  <script type="text/template" id="quotes-template">
    <% _.each(quotes, function(quote) { %>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <%=quote.source %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%=quote.context %>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% }); %>
  </script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using variable `quotes` in the underscore template, but the data you're passing to `_.template()` does not contain `quotes`.

Your code should be:

```
quotes.fetch({
  /*---------------collection----------------*/
  /*-------------------v----------------*/
  success: function(quotes, response, options) {
    var variables = {
      search: "search"
    }; // ...?
    var template = _.template($('#quotes-template').html(), {
      quotes: quotes
    });
    that.$el.html(template);
  }
});
```

Since the first argument `quotes` in your success callback is a `Backbone.Collection`, you might also want to change the template as follows, else you can pass the second argument, which is the actual response to `_.templte()`.

```
<body>
  <div class="quote-list"></div>

  <script type="text/template" id="quotes-template">
    <% _.each(quotes.models, function(quote) { %>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <%=quote.get("source") %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%=quote.get("context") %>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% }); %>
  </script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. I also tried throwing in a simple dummy object and still was getting the same error. For some reason nothing is getting passed to the template

Comment: @user3417966: [As of Underscore 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881231/479863) you can't say `h = _.template(tmpl, variables)` anymore, you have to `t = _.template(tmpl); h = t(variables)` now. So `template` is actually a function in your code and jQuery is executing that function ([but not with the expected arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26367958/479863)) when you `that.$el.html(template)`.